# MsgBox displaying differently when run in VBA editor

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs on opening an Excel file.
It scans a spreadsheet for due dates then shows names and a description of the item about to expire in a MSGBOX.
Each name and item description is on its own line, and the MSGBOX is titled according to which message it's displaying.

Problem is, when the file is opened it triggers the MSGBOX fine, but the box is untitled and it only lists names all on one line with no description.
However, when I run the macro in the VBA editor it's fine, all info displayed and formatted as per the code, and the correct title is displayed in the MSGBOX.

What am I doing wrong here? The code is ok as it runs fine in VBA editor but obviously I'm missing something to make it display correctly on startup.

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim DateDueCol As Range
Dim DateDue As Range
Dim NotificationMsg As String

Set DateDueCol = Range("F8:F12, I8:I12, L8:L12, O8:O12") 'the range of cells that contain your due dates

For Each DateDue In DateDueCol

    'Change B2 to the cell for bring forward reminder days in your data
    If Date >= DateDue - Range("B2") Then
    'Change the offset value to pick up the invoice number column in your data
        NotificationMsg = IIf(NotificationMsg = "", DateDue.Offset(0, -DateDue.Column + 1) & ":  " & DateDue.Offset(-DateDue.Row + 6, -2), NotificationMsg & vbLf & vbLf & DateDue.Offset(0, -DateDue.Column + 1) & ":  " & DateDue.Offset(-DateDue.Row + 6, -2))
        
    End If

Next DateDue

If NotificationMsg = "" Then

    MsgBox "Records indicate all sub-contractor cover is currently valid.", Title:="Cover OK!"

    
Else: MsgBox "The followinging sub-contractors' cover is missing or about to expire: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & NotificationMsg, Title:="Expiry Warning!"

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Would be best to qualify all `Range` calls with the worksheet in question.

Comment: I'm unable to repro this issue. Message box has a title and no matter which new line char I use, it works fine when opening the workbook.

Comment: Try changing `If Date >= DateDue - Range("B2") Then` to `If DateDiff("d", DateDue, Date) >= Range("B2") Then` Also as @BigBen said, instead of just using `Range` try `Sheet1.range` or whichever sheet. But as @ArcherBird said, I cannot reproduce. Perhaps posing your sheet data would help.

Comment: Hi Big Ben, are you referring to the "range"(B2)" in the code? 
B2 is the only cell in the range. It contains the number of days before the due date that it starts sending reminders (7). 

The "range" bit is in there as it was in the code I copied and adapted from an instructional page for a similar task. Could it be removed?

Comment: Hi ArcherBird. Weird, I wonder why it wouldn't work for me, could it be a local setting somewhere deep in a menu that I need to change? I've tried it on 2 different machines with different versions of Excel and I get the same result; ok in editor but wonky when opening the file.

Comment: Hi VCD_WL. I've tried the suggested changes to the code and used Sheet1.range as well, unfortunately the issue persists on startup